# When should or shouldn't I use a more general variable type for referencing my object?

Tags: java, subtype

There are 2 classes `A` and `B`, `B` extends `A`. What is the difference between

```
A a = new B();
```

and

```
B b = new B()?
```

Both create the object of class B. What is the difference?

Comment: A a = new B(); creates the object of A, but referencing  to class A. Object a get the properties of class A.

Comment: Relevant, although not directly an answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6854993/how-does-java-get-to-know-which-implementation-object-of-interface-to-return/6856001#6856001

Answer (score 3):

You are right that in both cases an object of class `B` is created.  The difference between the two declarations is in the type of the *variable*.

It is very important to keep the distinction between variables and objects in mind.  For example, the following code defines **3** variables but only **2** objects:

```
Circle c1 = new Circle(5);
Circle c2 = c1;
Circle c3 = new Circle(5);
```

When you say

```
Shape s = new Circle(5);
```

instead of

```
Circle s = new Circle(5);
```

assuming `Circle` extends `Shape` then, even though in both cases you did create a circle object, in the former case you can only call shape methods on the circle (through the variable `s`) whereas in the second case you can you all circle methods (because you will be calling them through the circle variable `c`).  That is a call like `s.getArea()` will work in both cases but something like `s.getRadius()` will ONLY be allowed in the second (unless you use an ugly cast).

So why do we often do things like the first case?  That is, why do we often define our variables of a more general type than necessary?  Usually we do this because we want to restrict the interface for safety.  Perhaps we only care about shapes, but in this case the particular shape just *happens to be* a circle.  If you cared about circle specific properties, then we would have used a circle variable.  But we should strive to be as general as possible.  Coding to the most general interface allows our code to work with shapes other than circles without modification.

Of course, for this to really sink in, you have to experience it firsthand, but hopefully this explanation is a start.  There are many books and blog posts and articles that explain this in more detail with useful real-life anecdotes I'm sure.

Answer (score 1):

The advantage is

```
Fruit f = new Mango();
```

Suppose

```
consumeFruit(Fruit f);
```

now you can call

```
consumeFruit(new Mango());
consumeFruit(new Strawberry());
```

**Note:**
For this case you would be only able to call the methods declared in the reference type. and object type's version will get invoked . and you would be only accessing fields from the reference type's class

**See Also**

- [Liskov substitution principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle)

Comment: Note that you can still call these methods with `Mango f = new Mango()`.

Comment: -1: you didn't answer the question about the *difference* between the two pieces of code, only talked about some advantage.

Comment: @Roland Illig  advantage is the difference.also see the *Note* section

Answer (score 1):

```
A a = new B();
```

has only the attributes and methods of A.

```
B b = new B();
```

has the the attributes and methods of B.
If you added some attributes or methods to B, you can't call them with a.

Comment: ... unless you cast `a` into `B`

Comment: Well, the object has all the attributes it has no matter what you call it. It will just be hidden from the compiler.

Comment: @Thilo: Thanks, that's new for me. I only knew, that you can't use them.

Answer (score 1):

If you say

```
List a = new ArrayList();
```

then you reference ArrayList only in one place in your code. That makes it easier to change it later to something else, like LinkedList;

Of course, this does not work if you need methods specific to ArrayList.

In general, you should use the most general type applicable.

Comment: -1 This is about programme to an interface not about inheritance. Bad example

Comment: I think it applies just as well to parent classes (which also implicitly define an interface via the methods they expose).

Comment: I concur Thilo. Actually, this example explains exactly the principle behind what is asked: information hiding.

Answer (score 0):

This question is on Polymorphism. Following is an extract from Kathy Siera:

    
`public class TestAnimals {

       public static void main (String [] args) {

Animal a = new Animal();

Animal b = new Horse(); //Animal ref, but a Horse object

a.eat(); // Runs the Animal version of eat()

b.eat(); // Runs the Horse version of eat()

}

}

class Animal {

public void eat() {

System.out.println("Generic Animal Eating Generically");

}

}

class Horse extends Animal {

private void eat() { // whoa! - it's private!

System.out.println("Horse eating hay, oats, "

+ "and horse treats");

}

}`

 
If this code compiled (which it doesn't), the following would fail at runtime:
Animal b = new Horse(); // Animal ref, but a Horse
// object , so far so good
b.eat(); // Meltdown at runtime!

Answer (score 0):

Suppose this example:

We have class an animal:

```
public class Animal {

  public void eat() {
     // each animal can eat
  }
}
```

Now we have another class dog:

```
public class Dog  extends Animal {

   public void bark() {
      // dogs can bark
   }
}
```

Now we can write this code:

```
Animal pet = new Dog();
```

Now we know, that `pet` can eat, but nothing more. But if we write

```
Dog pet = new Dog();
```

Then we know, that our pet can eat and bark.

Also there is safe and unsafe casting. Safe casting is from `Dog` to an `Animal` because each dog is animal (extends it)

```
Dog pet = new Dog(); 
Animal animal = pet;
```

But if we want to cast Animal to Dog we have to test if the instance of animal is really dog, because it doesn't have to be.

```
Animal pet = new Dog();
Dog myDog = null;
if (pet instanceof Dog) {
    myDog = (Dog) pet;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually, declaring a parent class and assigning it an inherited class is useful when the parent class variable may be assigned different objects. For example

```
Pet p;
if (favoritePet == Pets.CAT) {
   p = new Cat();
} else {
   p = new Dog();
}

System.out.println(p.someMethodFromPet());
```